# Derivation involving delta function

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

In some of my notes on physics I am currently reading, I stumbled across something I don't understand... How do I derive$\frac{1}{\hbar^2}|\int_0^tdt'e^{i(E_n-E_m)t'/\hbar}|^2\space\space$$\rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{\hbar^2} [\frac{\sin(\omega_{nm}t/2)}{\omega_{nm}/2}]^2$ $\rightarrow$ $t\frac{2\pi}{\hbar} \delta(E_n-E_m)$ for large times. Where $\omega_{nm} = (E_n-E_m)/\hbar$  ?

Comment: Do you have any more information than that?

Comment: Sorry no, that's why I'm asking... ( The derivation is done in the chapter on the Fermis golden rule in quantum mechanics, if that's of any help... )

Comment: Hmm, I can see where some of it is coming from but not the full package. Hopefully someone else can get somewhere with it. Just out of interest do you know how to take the integral of $e^{((A-B)/H)t}$ where we can consider $A,B$ and $H$ as constants?

Comment: $\int e^{\frac{A-B}{H}t}= \frac{H}{A-B}e^{\frac{A-B}{H}t}+const.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \left |\int_0^a e^{ikx} dx \right |= \left | \frac{e^{ika} - 1}{ik}\right | = \left |e^{i \frac{ka}{2}} \frac{e^{i\frac{ka}{2}} - e^{-i\frac{ka}{2}}}{ik}\right | = \left |\frac{2e^{i \frac{ka}{2}}}{k} \frac{e^{ik\frac{a}{2}} - e^{-i\frac{ka}{2}}}{2i} \right | = $$

$$\left | \frac{2 e^{i\frac{ka}{2}} }{k} \cdot \sin\left (\frac{ka}{2}\right )\right | = \left | e^{i\frac{ka}{2}} \cdot \frac{\sin \left ( \frac{ka}{2} \right )}{\frac{k}{2}}\right | = \left |  \frac{\sin \left ( \frac{ka}{2} \right )}{\frac{k}{2}}\right |$$

Now substitute the right parameters and bingo.

Comment: How does this produce a delta function?

Comment: There is a definition of $\delta(x)$ using the limit of $sinc(Nx)/N , N\to \infty$ , are you familiar with it?

Comment: No, that's the problem, I didn't know about this kind of representation for the delta function.... Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: You're very welcome! :) 
If you need held with deriving that definition you're welcome to ask for help.